# Wordpress css bug in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have built a webpage, it works fine in chrome, ff, but not in IE. 
http://www.magyarregeszet.hu/

I have found many specific bugs about tables and layout, however I can't seem to figure out the font and text-transform type bugs.

Can someone help me? E.g. the menu entryes on the top left should be uppercase in IE too. This entry is:

```
.menu-item:not(.menu-item-77)  {
    color: white;   
    text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight:normal;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;    
        text-decoration: none;  
}
```

I use wordpress, and the constructor theme.

Comment: which IE version are you referring to?

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on? Are you declaring DOCTYPE?

Comment: It should be compatible from IE8.

Comment: Only <!DOCTYPE html> . What DOCTYPE should be declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `:not` pseudo-class in IE8, check http://caniuse.com/#search=:not for support. Internet Explorer 9+ supports this advanced selector.

If you require IE8 support, I would encourage you to  provide your basic styles:

```
.menu-item {
    color: #FFF
}
```

And then your specific styles afterward:

```
.menu-item-77 {
    color: #CCC
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/w39a7/

Answer (score 1):

`:not` is not compatible with IE8 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html